# How to add extra header to post request with vue-resource?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I have a number of post requests in my app. Some of them have to have and extrace header with `token` I'm not sure how to append it

So far my code is like this. I'm checking if there is a token and when append it to headers and after that I make post request with vue-resource post method.

```
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});

 if(token !== '') {
    headers.append('TOKEN', token);
  }

  return this.http.post(uri, data, headers)
         .then(this.extractData)
         .catch(this.handleError);
```

But this doesn't append `TOKEN`

What does work is this

```
this.http.interceptors.push(function(request) {
                request.headers.set('TOKEN', token);
            });
```

at the place of `headers.append('TOKEN', token);`

But for some reason it pushes `TOKEN` header not for certain requests but for all of them

So when I'm make request with token - it works fine, after that I make request witthout token but it is still adds it.

Anyone knows what is the best way to fix this?

**UPD** If I `console.log(headers.get('TOKEN'))` while doing `headers.append('TOKEN', token);` it gives me the right value. So my guess is that post request itself is called with wrong headers.

Comment: You are using once the method `set()` and once `append()`. On purpose?

Comment: the bit with `set` I took from docs https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#interceptors

Comment: I'm having the same question. I can't add extra request headers via $http, fetch(), axios!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [document](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md), `headers` should be normal Javascript object, not `window.Headers`

Please try

```
  let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  };

  if(token !== '') {
    headers['TOKEN'] = token
  }

  return this.http.post(uri, data, {headers})
         .then(this.extractData)
         .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Yes, just tried it. If I console.log headers they are right, but request is still without them.

Comment: The third param is a config object. Shouldn't it then have `headers` as a key in it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I figured it out. Thanks to comment by @ssc-hrep3 and answer by @ittus

```
let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      };

      if(token !== '') {
        headers['TOKEN'] = token
      }

      return this.http.post(uri, data, {headers: headers})
             .then(this.extractData)
             .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Basic Token";
```

Comment: What file is that ? What Vue version ? 2?